# detect if a column contains special characters in postgresql table

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have a table in PostgreSQL and I need to detect if a column contains special characters like `#,$,^,&,*,@,!` etc. or is empty.

For example the table might be like this

[image]

How to write a query like this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Finally i got the solution

```
select * from table where column1 ~* '[^a-z0-9]' or column2  ~* '[^a-z0-9]' or column3  ~* '[^a-z0-9]'
```

Comment: What is this operator `~*` called ?

Comment: @mantri It is one of the regular expression match operators: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#id-1.5.8.12.8.2

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer resp. SQL Query